# Is a NSManagedObject subclass can have relationship of this same class type?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-data

I'm working with CoreData and I would like to know if I can have this type of relationship:

I have a `NSManagedObject` subclass named `Station`. In this class, I want to add a relationship named `nextStation` of type Station. Is this possible in CoreData?

If not, how can I do to perform what I want?

Comment: Did you try it? Did you experience any problems? Hint: Read the section "Relationship Fundamentals" in the "Core Data Programming Guide".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure, reflexive relationships are possible!!

From Apple doc:

> A relationship specifies the entity, or the parent entity, of the
>   objects at the destination. This can be the same as the entity at the
>   source (a reflexive relationship).

For further info see [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-CJBDBHCB) and [Relationship section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectModeling/ObjectModeling.html).